# Can not attach an image file to my post on Cross Validated

Tags: support, markdown

I've posted a question here:

[Chi-square test restriction for contingency tables with observed counts](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/461428/chi-square-test-restriction-for-contingency-tables-with-observed-counts)

I'm not able to attach a picture file with the table I've mentioned in the question. The markup renders as code rather than as the image.
Could you help me please? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You'd get much better help on your [own meta](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/) rather than here.

Comment: Is it not the right place for my question?

Comment: @RobertLongson The question is on-topic here, as it's a Markdown issue that anyone can face on any site in the network and is helpful to other users facing a similar issue on a different site.

Comment: @RobertLongson Much appreciated for your help. Will delete my post from here.

Comment: No need to delete your post. It's on-topic here.

Comment: The "site-specific" close reason applies to posts that are *truly* related to one specific site, that can only be truly answered by users of that site in a manner that pertains to that site only (e.g. site scope discussions). Things that can have general answers that pertain to other sites should *not* be closed with that reason (cc @RobertLongson and other close voters)

Comment: @SonictheStay-HomeHedgehog yes but they can help him more easily there as they can edit the post for him.

Comment: @RobertLongson True, they might get better help there, but that doesn't mean that the question is necessarily *off-topic* here.

Comment: In [the question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/revisions/461428/1) you didn't use *any* "markup" (MathJax), you simply copied the table entries into the question and (presumably) expected it to look the same as where you copied it from. There are many ways of doing it, you probably wanted: $$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c} ... ---- Such as here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/29979/510296

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a few spaces before the image markup. Any line with four spaces in the beginning [is treated as code markup](https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#code), which results in that line rendering as code. Markdown within code markup is not parsed, so that the characters themselves can be shown.

To fix the issue, remove the spaces before the line, so it just begins with the opening bracket.